# nil values weirdness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I have faced a simple situation that I can't figure out.

I have to decide whether to show the "more" link, depending of the articles count.

The code is simple:

```
@no_more = offset + length >= Article.count
```

`@no_more` variable equals to nil sometimes. I see in the debugger that `offset = 0`, `length = 10` and `Article.count = 12`

But the expression above gives nil.

Even this doesn't help:

```
@no_more = false if @no_more.nil?
```

`@no_more` will still be nil.

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Where you execute assignment and where you use variable? Can it be that assignment is not executed?

Comment: "@no_more" is used in view to show or not to show "more" link. I don't know, how to force the assigment to be executed. @no_more is nil, i see it in debugger.

Comment: Ok, but where @no_more is assigned? In controller?

Comment: Yes. It is assigned in controller and used for decision in a view

Comment: Try logging it in controller to see if it's actually assigned. Something like _puts "my value goes here: #{my_value}"_

Comment: Please paste here your action code from controller and also paste part of a view where it is used.

Comment: `0 + 10 >= 12` should never evaluate to `nil` under normal circumstances. There must be something more going on here.

Answer (score 1):

what about not-not assignment?

```
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > @no_more
 => nil 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > !!@no_more
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > @no_more = true
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > !!@no_more
 => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses:

```
@no_more = ((offset + length) >= Article.count)
```

The precedence works oddly without them, so Ruby interprets your code in that way.

Comment: I tried, what you suggested, but i get the same: @no_more equals to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not resetting the @no_more variable somewhere else in your controller or view, especially if you are doing a redirect.

Comment: No, i have traced the program in debugger. Current position of the program pointer points to @no_more variable, mentioned first time (first code fragment in my question), and in the next step it still equals to nil, after the condition (second code fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Try printing @no_more.class and check if it really is a NilClass and not a FalseClass.

I say this because I had the same problem the other day. This was with the debugger in netbeans (and jruby for that matter), but the debugger did not seem to understand the FalseClass.

for example this code:

```
p = false
puts p.class
```

For me this ofcourse printed FalseClass, but the debugger insisted p was a NilClass. I confirmed with "kind_of?" that it really was a FalseClass.

You could try checking the same things.

```
@no_more.kind_of?(FalseClass)
```

Just thought I'd mention this in case it's the same problem as I had. It kept me busy half the night trying to figure out wtf was going on.